# Champion.GG Api: get data over file_get_contents cut off string

Tags: php, json, api

If I want to get the data from `champion.gg` over my browser, I get everything.
If I try to get it over `file_get_contents`, I only get the half page

after "Galio" the string is cut off.

Chrome: http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=PRIVATE
about 86.000 chars
file_get_contents("http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=PRIVATE");
about 45.000 chars

Answer (score 1):

Try using cURL:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.champion.gg/stats?api_key=PRIVATE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data); // $data should contain the response
```

Increase the timeout value if you get incomplete responses.