# File Get Contents only gets part of JSON data and not all contents

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-scraping

The code below does not fetch all the JSON content in the URL provided but part of it, I can't find any problem with it:

```
$json=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap-static"); 
$data = json_decode($json, true); 
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422113/champion-gg-api-get-data-over-file-get-contents-cut-off-string?rq=1

Comment: I get no data while I use curl as shown on the link above

Comment: Updated answer. I just ran this code and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/bootstrap static");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$jdecoded = json_decode($data, true); 
curl_close($ch);

print_r($jdecoded);
```

Comment: It was not working on wamp server but I have tested with the web server and its fine. Thanks

Comment: Check the "post_max_size" and "memory_limit" PHP INI settings on your wamp server. It's possible that these are set too low.